# Eclipse Java some breakpoints work on debug others not

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, jboss

As title says, im working on a legacy code on my company, using Java and Jboss as a server on Eclipse, i added some breakpoints to debug some things, started the server, i can mess around all i want, but for some reason half of the breakpoints i add on the part of the code im working just dont work, like they are not aknowlegded by Eclipse that they are there and are completely ignored when called. Like in the image below, the first bp stops as normal, but the other ones simply are ignored.
[breakpoints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGFgg.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: maybe the execution skips the line on which you have the breakpoint caused by certain if conditions. Try to put a breakpoint at the beginning of the method and then use step over.